# pthread_join() fail on ios

Tags: c++, ios, pthreads

I am working on a multithread project on IOS.
In my project a pthread joining is failing sometime.

```
pthread_join(thread_id, NULL) == 0
```

Note: this is only occurring on IOS and it is random.
What can be the reason to failing the join operation.

Comment: Since your question is very broad (no code, no details), the answer has to be broad, too: **The reason is you made a mistake somewhere, sometime.** (for a more detailed answer, provide more details in your question, e.g. an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and the error message you get.

Comment: ios doesnt return error codes when it fails?

Comment: the error code will give you a clue: http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/pthread_join/

Comment: `pthread_join()` returns `-1` on error and in this case sets `errno` to a value specifying what kind of error occured. You might like to use `perror()`  or `strerror()` to print out a text describing the error indicated by the value `errno` had been set to.

Answer (score 2):

Man page Says:

ERRORS
     pthread_join() will fail if:

```
 [EDEADLK]          A deadlock was detected or the value of thread speci-
                    fies the calling thread.

 [EINVAL]           The implementation has detected that the value speci-
                    fied by thread does not refer to a joinable thread.

 [ESRCH]            No thread could be found corresponding to that speci-
                    fied by the given thread ID, thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and have found a simple solution: don't call pthread_detach(). According to documentation, pthread_detach moves the tread into a state where it can no longer be joined, so pthread_join fails with EINVAL.

The source code could look something like this:

```
pthread_t       thread;
pthread_attr_t  threadAttr;

bool run = true;
void *runFunc(void *p) {
    while (run) { ... }
}

- (void)testThread {
    int status = pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr);
    NSLog(@"pthread_attr_init status: %d", status);
    status = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&threadAttr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    NSLog(@"pthread_attr_setdetachstate status: %d", status);
    status = pthread_create(&thread, &threadAttr, &runFunc, (__bridge void *)self);
    NSLog(@"pthread_create status: %d", status);
    /* let the thread run ... */
    run = false;
    status = pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    NSLog(@"pthread_join status: %d == %d, ?", status, EINVAL);
}
```